# How do I populate a gallery and Imageswitcher quickly?

Tags: android, optimization, memory-leaks, android-gallery, imageswitcher

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory, OnItemSelectedListener {  
 private Gallery gallery;                                                                            
 private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;                               
 private ImageAdapter ia;   
 private int res_id;
 private Bitmap mBitmap;

 @Override  
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

      gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);                    
      imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.image_switcher);  

      imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);             
      imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  
                android.R.anim.fade_in));  
      imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  
                android.R.anim.fade_out));  



      ia = new ImageAdapter(this);  
      gallery.setAdapter(ia);  

      //Event listener
      gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  
 }  
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
 {
     MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
     menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
     return true;
 }
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 {

     switch (item.getItemId())
     {
         case R.id.menu_save:


        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),res_id);

        String filename = "barca_"+res_id+".jpg";
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String full_path=sd.getAbsolutePath()+"/BarcaWallpapers/";
        File temp=new File(full_path);
        temp.mkdirs();
        File dest = new File(temp,filename);
        try {
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
               mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
              Toast.makeText(this, "Saved in Folder "+full_path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
         return true;

     case R.id.menu_set_wallpapaer:
         final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);

        try{

        wallpaperManager.setResource(res_id);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "error setting wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
         return true;

     default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
 }    
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {  
 } 




 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
     int imageResourceId = (Integer) ia.getItem(position); 

     res_id=imageResourceId;

     imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageResourceId);

}  



public View makeView() {  
     ImageView i = new ImageView(this);  
     i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER); 

     i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
     return i;  
}  


 private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
      private Context context;  

      private ImageAdapter(Context context) {  
           this.context = context;  
      }  

      private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {  
               R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6,

                   };  

      public int getCount() {  
           return IMAGE_IDS.length;  
      }  

      public Object getItem(int position) {  
           return IMAGE_IDS[position];  
      }  

      public long getItemId(int position) {  
          return IMAGE_IDS[position];
      }  

      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

             ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  
        imageView = new ImageView(context);


        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(120,120));

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[position]);

    return imageView;


      }  
 }
```

}

I have the above code for a wallpaper app. The activity xml layout file contains a gallery view and a imageswitcher below it in which the user can browse and navigate through the gallery and the corresponding image opens up below in the imageswitcher. User can then set the image as a wallpaper or save to sd card. The above code works perfectly for small images, but fails miserably for large images like the one I intend to have in the app. The app crashes when it runs out of memory(openglrenderer is out of memory). How do I fix this? Pls help me, Ive spent many a hour on this problem.
Thanks